# Listings fails if I call it too much - Package xkeyval: `LANGUAGE' undefined in families `lst'

Tags: listings

I am writing a document with some customizations around the `listings` package:

- A `lstjson` environment defined via `\lstnewenvironment`
- A `\restsection` command, which is used as `\section` but wraps the section header with `\lstinline`
- A `\lstitem` command, which does as above with `\item`

The structure seemed to work, but as document grew it stopped compiling.
The error is

```
Package xkeyval: `LANGUAGE' undefined in families `lst'
```

A (non)working example follows. The strange thing is that it seems to depend on how much I use listings: if you remove enough `\lstitem`s or "some kind of field" lines it will compile.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{color}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
}

\lstdefinelanguage{rest}
{
    morekeywords={GET,POST,CREATE,UPDATE,DELETE},
    keywordstyle=\color{red}
}

\newcommand{\restsection}[1]
    {
        \section{
            \texorpdfstring
                {\lstinline[language={rest}]|#1|}
                {#1}
        }
    }

\lstnewenvironment{lstjson}
    {\lstset{
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
    }}
    {}

\newcommand{\lstitem}[2]
    {
        \item \lstinline|#1| \\
            #2
    }

%end of preamble

\title{Non-Working Example}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chp:Introduction}

This is the introduction.

%This section works
\restsection{POST /api/login}
\label{api:login}

Used to authenticate.

\subsection*{Payload}

\begin{lstjson}
{
  "username": String,
  "password": String
}      
\end{lstjson}

\subsection*{Response}

\begin{lstjson}
{
    stuff
}
\end{lstjson}

%This section does not work
\restsection{DataStructure}
\label{data:DataStructure}

\subsection*{Schema}

\begin{lstjson}
    {
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
        some kind of field
    }
\end{lstjson}

\subsection*{Description of fields}

\begin{itemize}
    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }

    \lstitem{stuff}{
        stuff
    }    
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: LANGUAGE is a key hint here. Have you tried adding this this the preamble: `\nouppercaseheads\pagestyle{headings} ` the default headers in memoir are uppercased, thus uppercasing also hits variable arguments. Simply easier to switch them off, I don't think upper cased headers are recommended anymore anyway

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the example but the main document still has errors. Are there other defaults that could be an issue?

Comment: I have no idea what you do in your real document. So you'll have to prepare another mwe and hunt down examples of what is not fixed with this suggestion. Don't delete the original mwe, it might be useful to others. I probably wouldn't have put lstinline in sections to begin with.

Comment: About the use of `\listinline` in section, I am using `\texorpdfstring` to avoid issues, isn't that enough?

About the issues in the document, I experimented some more and the issue appears when lines in a `lstlisting` are going to be split across two pages. In fact I can compile either by removing lines inside the environment or by adding a `\clearpage` before.

The error given is

`Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. <recently read> \egroup`

and the reported line is the one where the page break happens

Comment: Texorpdfstring only deals with bookmark via hyperref.

Comment: While the issue in the title is know fixed, I still have errors when a listing should go across pages. Should I update this question (and title) or create a new one?

Comment: @rzippo I think updating is fine, as the issues both seem closely related to the preamble setup.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP found a solution for the main problem from the comments, and no details are provided for the follow-up problem

Comment: Sorry, I was going to redo the mwe but didn't get around it . I will self-answer this and make another question for the other issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer via comments (credits to daleif) for the mwe provided, but issues still arose in the main document. I still have however to isolate them to a new mwe, as the document is now working thanks to the `\clearpage` workaround. In the meantime I am closing this with daleif's answer.

LANGUAGE is a key hint here. Have you tried adding this to the preamble: `\nouppercaseheads\pagestyle{headings}` the default headers in memoir are uppercased, thus uppercasing also hits variable arguments. Simply easier to switch them off, I don't think upper cased headers are recommended anymore anyway.